# Count number of elements above a certain theshold within sublists in a list

Tags: r, list

I have the following list with sublists, I would like to find out the positions within each sublist > 1 and come out with a list of the same structure with the results.

```
L <- list ( list( c ( 1 ,  1 ,  1 ,  1 ,  1 ,  1 ,  1 ,  1 ,  1 ,  1 ,139 ,  1  , 1 ,139 ,  1 ,139 ,139 , 1 ,139 ,139 ,139  , 1  , 1  , 1  , 1  , 1  , 1  , 1  , 1  , 1) , c( 1 ,3 ,1 ,1 ,3 ,1 ) , c( 74 ,74  ,1 ,74 ,74 ,74  ,1  ,1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 ,74 , 1 , 1 ,74 , 1 ,74 ,74  ,1) , c( 7 ,7 ,7 ,1 ,1 ,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ,1))  , list ( c ( 1 ,1 ,139, 1 ,1 ,139 ,1 ,1 ,139 ,  1 ,  1 ,139 ,  1 ,  1 ,139 ,  1 ,  1 ,139 ,139  , 1 ,139  , 1  , 1 ,139 , 1 , 1 ,139 , 1 , 1 ,139), c( 1 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,1 ,3 ) , c(  1 , 1 ,74 ,74 , 1 ,74  ,1 , 1 ,74 , 1 , 1 ,74 , 1 , 1 ,74 , 1 , 1 ,74 , 1 , 1 ,74 ,74 , 1 ,74) , c(  7, 1, 7, 1, 1, 7, 1, 1, 7, 1, 1, 7 ))  ,  list ( c ( 1 ,128 ,1 ,1 ,128 ,1 ,128 ,128 ,1 ,128 ,128 ,128 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 , 1 ,128, 1) , c( integer(0) ), c( integer(0) ) , c( integer(0) ) , c( integer(0) ) , c( integer(0) ))  , list (c( 1 ,1 ,128 ,1 ,1 ,128 ,128 ,1 ,128 ,128 ,1 ,128 ,1 ,1 ,128 ,1 ,1 ,128 ,1 ,1 ,128 ,1   ,1 ,128 ) , c( integer(0) ), c( integer(0) ) , c( integer(0) ) , c( integer(0) ) , c( integer(0) )))
```

I have tried embedding a function within a function and use mapply as follows however I get an error.

```
fun  <-  function ( i ) {                   
ss    <- seq ( length ( L [[ i ]] ))
Map ( function ( a ,  b ) which ( L [[ a ]] [[ b ]] > 1 ) , ss[[ i ]] , MoreArgs = ( a = list ( seq ( length ( L ))  )))      
                         }         
lapply ( seq ( length ( L )) , fun )
```

Any help is welcomed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you want

```
rapply(L, function(x) which(x>1), how = "list")
```